# Symfony 5: Expected argument of type "string", "object" given at property path "myEntity"

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am having an issue with the EntityType class in Symfony 5 where I cannot find a way to make the form row return a `string` instead of an entity (`MyEntity`). This is what I basically have as part of the form builder:

```
$builder->add('myEntity', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => MyEntity::class,
                'placeholder' => "(Please select an option.)",
                'choice_label' => 'name'
            ])
```

My aim is to have this field return the `name` for the `MyEntity` selected, not the entire entity (so, the exact same value as the `'choice_label'`). I've already tried adding a `'choice_value' => 'name'` attribute (with a `'mapped' => false` attribute, which is apparently necessary in that case), but to no avail. More precisely, the form row starts returning `null` rather than a `string` for any entity.

How would I be able to achieve my goal?

Comment: You configured it as expecting an entity - why would you expect anything else? I believe [data transformers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out that defining the __toString() function in `MyEntity` for the `name` field (the exact same way you would define the getter method for the `name` field) fixed it, and I now get no errors plus a successful submission to the DB. Case closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that defining the [`__toString()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#:%7E:text=The%20__toString()%20method,E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR%20level%20error%20is%20emitted.) in `MyEntity` as returning the `name` field (the exact same way you would define `getName()`) fixed it, and I now get no errors plus a successful submission to the DB.

```
public function __toString() {
    return $this->name;
}
```

(In case you're wondering why just this addition and nothing else fixes it, it's because `__toString` is already being used by default in some pre-existing entity-related code to express an entity in a simpler and custom way, if I'm not mistaken. Now that I made this function available, it's going to go to it and safely assume that when my entity might need to be expressed in a simpler [string] format, `__toString` should be called to "transform" `MyEntity` into a meaningful string, such as its `name`. I guess all that is to say that for instance, you won't refer to a car by all of its internal parts, but rather by just its model.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you found the right solution, but it didn't work for me.
I use the EntityType in its own Type which is called in a CollectionType (yes, something special).
To solve the problem for me, I used the DataTransformer, as follows:

```
class ProductTextTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{

  public function reverseTransform($text)
  {
      if (null === $text) {
          return '';
      }

      return $text->getName();
  }

  public function transform($name)
  {
      // NOTE: Should not Called!
  }
}
```